# Publishing angular 8 site using a configuration does not work

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an angular 8 site and I am trying to publish it locally and then deploy it. During the `build` step I specify an environment name that I have defined as `internalprod`:

```
src
├───app
├───environments
│       environment.Debug.ts
│       environment.InternalProd.ts
│       environment.PreLive.ts
│       environment.prod.ts
│       environment.Test.ts
│       environment.ts
└───js
```

environment.InternalProd.ts

```
export const environment = {
...
  environmentName: "InternalProd"
};
```

angular.json

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
...
          "configurations": {
...
            "internalprod": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.InternalProd.ts"
                }
              ],
              "baseHref": "/",
              "deployUrl": "/",
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "commonChunk": true,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "poll": 500
            },
...
}
```

To build the project I `cd` into the `src` dir and use the command `npm run ng build --configuration=internalprod`

However, when I inspect the `dist/myproject/main-es5.js` and  `dist/myproject/main-es2015.js` files and navigate to the `var environment =` section I do not see the variables being replaced with the `internalProd` configuration file:

```js
    var environment = {
      ...
      environmentName: "Development"
      }
    };
```

Apparently, the `environment.Debug.ts` file gets picked up as this is the only file setting the `environmentName` var to `Development` but I do not understand why that happens.

Comment: Does the configuration is on the `build` parat on the angular.json?. Why do you `cd` into `src`?, the `package.json` is not outside the `src` folder?. 

Can you please execute the command with `=`?, I execute it like you and I got an error (`--configuration=internalprod `)

Comment: Also according to this post https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/13560 You may execute your command starting with two dashes `npm run ng build -- --configuration=internalprod `

Comment: Thank you for your comments! TBH, I am not sure why I was running the build command in the `src` folder. I ran it in the root of the project and also added the `--` so that the arguments are passed to the `ng` command and it worked! I got my settings replaced correctly with the internalprod settings. 

Please add your comment as an answer, I would be happy to accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [post](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/13560) you may execute your command starting with two dashes `npm run ng build -- --configuration=internalprod` and probably outside the `src` folder.

Cheers!